# Create password protected zip file in Java without creating it on disk

Tags: java, zip

I need a create zip file. It should be password protected. I am using lingala jar. Here is my below. Is there a way to do it? I even tried zipoutstream, couldn't find a way to add password.

```
@Component
public class FileZipUtils {

    @Value("${candela.email.zip.folder}")
    private String zipBaseDir;

    @Value("${candela.email.zip.encryptionmethod:AES}")
    private String encryptionMethod;

    @Value("${candela.email.zip.encryptionstrength:KEY_STRENGTH_128}")
    private String encryptionStrength;

    private ZipParameters zipParameters;

    @PostConstruct
    private void initializeZipProperties() {
        zipParameters = new ZipParameters();
        zipParameters.setEncryptFiles(true);
        zipParameters.setEncryptionMethod(EncryptionMethod.AES);
        zipParameters.setAesKeyStrength(AesKeyStrength.KEY_STRENGTH_128);
    }

    /*
     * Creates a zipfile in the zipBaseDir location
     */
    public ZipFile createZipFile(String zipFileName,char[] password) {
        return new ZipFile(zipBaseDir + "/" + zipFileName,password);
    }

    /**
     * Adds attachment to Zip file
     */
    public void addAttachementToZip(ZipFile zipFile, ByteArrayResource fileContentInBytes, String fileName)
            throws IOException {
        zipParameters.setFileNameInZip(fileName);
        zipFile.addStream(fileContentInBytes.getInputStream(), zipParameters);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we need to create file on disk.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for zip files `zip4j` lib.
 ([Github Link](https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/zip4j))

Features:

- Create, Add, Extract, Update, Remove files from a Zip file
- Support for streams (ZipInputStream and ZipOutputStream)
- Read/Write password protected Zip files and streams
- Support for both AES and Zip-Standard encryption methods
- Support for Zip64 format
- Store (No Compression) and Deflate compression method
- Create or extract files from Split Zip files (Ex: z01, z02,...zip)
- Support for Unicode file names and comments in zip
- Progress Monitor - for integration into apps and user facing applications

Comment: This is exactly what I have used.

Comment: anything for 7zip also?